# What the Bal Shem Tov Said

Tags: sources-mekorot, chasidut-hasidism, mussar-ethics, baal-shem-tov

There is "famous" thing that is said over in the name of the Baal Shem Tov. It's essentially that one who sees faults in others, really himself has that fault in themselves. And perhaps the one who sees the fault "more", the more he himself has that particular fault or bad trait, etc.

1. Is this written down anywhere? What is the source that the Baal Shem Tov said it?
2. Is this idea expressed anywhere else in Jewish literature?
3. Are there are those that disagree openly with this idea?

Comment: @doubleaa perhaps leaning this open would be beneficial. at the moment it seems to have a better sources answer than its earlier iteration.

Comment: @mevaqesh Maybe merging that here?

Comment: Consider marking an answer correct...  :)

Answer (score 6):

**Source in Jewish Literature**

The Talmud (kiddushin 70b) states that one who stigmatizes another is guilty of the same:

> ותני: כל הפוסל - פסול, ואינו מדבר בשבחא לעולם, ואמר שמואל: במומו פוסל
>   He who declares [others] unfit is [himself] unfit, and never speaks good [of anyone]; and Samuel said: With his own blemish he stigmatizes [others] as unfit.’ (Soncino Translation).

**Source that the Baal Shem Tov said it**

This does not say that he is necessarily worse, though.

This is also discussed by R. Ya'akov Yosef haCohen, a student of the Ba'al Shem Tov in his *Toldot Ya'akov Yosef* the first Hassidic book to ever be published (1780), in Parshat Shoftim where he quotes the Ba'al Shem Tov himself:

> שנותן דופי בבני אדם למצוא בהם מום וחסרון, ובפרט ששונא לעובדי ה' אז וודאי יש בו מום, כמאמר הש"ס בקדושין (ע א) ההוא דקרי לאינשי עבדי וכו', דכל הפוסל במומו פוסל וכו', **ומסתמא אדם זה בו כל דבר רע**, כמו ששמעתי ממורי זלה"ה

To summarize: one who criticizes others can be presumed to have every negative characteristic. In this the Ba'al Shem Tov extends the Talmud's statement that he possesses the same negative characteristics.

This idea is later cited in the Baal Shem Tov's collected comments to the Torah (B'reishit: 126):

> קכו. שנינו (נגעים ב', ה') כל הנגעים אדם רואה חוץ מנגעי עצמו, ופירש הבעל שם טוב הקדוש, כל הנגעים שאדם רואה חוץ, זה נמשך מנגעי עצמו, כמאמר רבותינו ז"ל (קידושין ע' א) כל הפוסל במומו פוסל: (דברי שלום פרשת קרח דף נ"ו ע"ב

There the Baal Shem Tov is cited as having homiletically explained the statement that "one may examine anyone's leprosy except one's own"  (Negaim 2:5) that that which one perceived as negative on others, stems from his possessing the same fault.

Comment: Although he does not disagree with the statement, Rabbi Menachem Meiri seems to tone it down a bit, writing in his commentary to that passage in Kiddushin: 
לעולם יזהר אדם שלא ירגיל לשונו לפגום את הבריות ולמעט במעלת זולתו בכונת לשון הרע והמעטת כבוד אחרים דרך קנאה וגאוה שאין זו אלא כחושד עצמו ומקנה לאחרים מיראתו עליהם שידעו בו שמץ פסול ויודיעוהו ועושה עצמו כמקדים לפורענות והוא שאמרו כל הפוסל פסול ואינו מדבר בשבחה לעולם ואמר שמואל ובמומו פוסל ומכל מקום לא נאמר כן אלא לחוש לו אבל להכריז עליו ולפרסמו שהוא כן לא אלא אם כן נודע בבירור שהוא כן

Comment: That is one who criticizes others is "like one who makes himself suspect and arouses the passions of others from imposing his fear on them, that they will know that he has traces of disqualification, and they will inform him...and this is the explanation of that which they said one who disqualifies is himself disqualified...Still this is not so say that it is definite, rather, that others ought to be wary". In his descriptions he seems to describe criticizing others as being indicative of merely "a trace of disqualification", not the full measure of what he accused others of.

Answer (score 3):

The original quote is

> תורתו של הבעל שם טוב, שכאשר אדם רואה רע בזולתו, הרי זו הוכחה ש(דוגמת) אותו הרע נמצא בו בעצמו. וכמו אדם המביט בראי – "אם פניו נקיים, אינו רואה במראה שום דופי", אבל אם הוא רואה לכלוך וכתם בראי, אין זה אלא משום ש"פניו מטונפין.

From the **hosafos** to Kesser Shem Tov (http://chabadlibrary.org/books/bsht/kst/3/176).

The Maarei Mekomos show to  מאור עינים ר"פ חקת. וראה גם תולדות יעקב יוסף ס"פ תרומה. ובכ"מ. וראה גם ספר השיחות קייץ ה'ש"ת ע' 83. תש"ח ע' 185

The Maor Einaim (A student of the Baal Shem Tov) [writes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24871&st=&pgnum=180):
[image]

---

For an explanation of why this should be true (after all, perhaps the other *is* evil), see [Likkutei Sichos Chelek Yud Parshas Noach](http://merkos302.com/living/likutei_sichos/02nch/nch10_2.pdf)

> והביאור בזה: כל מאורע שבעולם
> הוא בהשגחה פרטית. וכן גם במאורע
> זה (שהוא רואה רע בזולתו) אין זה.
> במקרה ח״ו, אלא דבר שהזמינו לו
> מלמעלה: ומכיוון שלא ברא הקב״ה
> בעולמו דבר אחד לבטלה״׳, הרי א״א
> לומר שמלמעלה יביאוהו לידי ראיית
> רע במישהו לשווא — אלא שבודאי
> יש בזה, ההוראה והודעה והיא —
> שהרע נמצא ברואה עצמו ועליו
> לתקנו
>
> אמנם עדיין יש להקשות: תפ־
> קידו של איש הישראלי, הוא לא רק
> לפעול זיכוך ועלי׳ בעצמו, אלא גם
> לפעול בחבירו, וכמש״נ הוכח תוכיח
> את עמיתך ואפילו מאה פעמים
>
> וא״כ: מי יאמר שהכוונה בזה שמ־
> למעלה הראוהו את הרע של זולתו
> הוא בכדי שיראה ויוודע שאותו הרע
> נמצא בו ואשר עליו לבערו! הרי
> יתכן לומר כפשוטו. שהכוונה באמת
> היא להראותו את ה״רע״ של חבירו
> — בכדי שהוא, הרואה. יוכיחו ויעזור
> לו לתקן ולהטיב דרכו?

...

> וע״ד שהוא בשייכות לענין הדיבור
> (בלשון נקיי) כמו״כ — בנוגע לראי׳:
> כאשר שומע שאיש מישראל עשה
> דבר בלתי הגון ח״ו, החובה בזה
> ״לראות״ את ״ההלכה למעשה״ שב־
> ה ענין: דהיינו (רק) מה שנוגע לזה
> שהוא (הרואה) צריך לעשות — לתקן:
> להוכיח אותו (כמובן, בדרכי נועם
> ובאופן הרצוי •=) ולהחזירו למוטב!
> עכ״פ זה צ״ל עיקר הראי׳. אמנם,
> אם בעת ששומע מהלא טוב של זולתו
> הרי הוא ״רואה״ לא את ההוראה
> למעשה המכוונת לו, אלא שהוא ״רו­
> אה״ רעתו של חבירו (עכ״פ — זה
> מודגש אצלו) — ז. א. שמרגיש (לא
> הנחיצות מצדו לתקנו, כ״א) איך שיש
> מציאות רע בזולתו — ה״ז ראי׳
> מוכחת ש״פניו מטונפיך, שהלא טוב
> שרואה בזולתו הוא ״ראי״ של הלא
> טוב שלו.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe explains that there are two ways one can see another's evil:

1. He sees something that needs fixing
2. He sees the **evil** in the other

He explains in the Sicha that only when one sees and focuses on evil is there a sign that there's something unhealthy going on ("a mirror"). However, if all he sees is that the person needs some help and some fixing, it's not a sign that there's anything wrong

Comment: Are you sure the Meor Einayim was a student of the Besht?

Answer (score 1):

*1. Is this written down anywhere? What is the source that the Baal Shem Tov said it?*

**Yes**

[כתר שם טוב > הוספות > קעה](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/bsht/kst/3/175.htm)

> הוכח תוכיח
>
> תורת הבעש"ט האָט אונז געלערנט דעם ענין פון הוכחה, אַז אַלע חסרונות זאָל מען זען אין זיך. אַז מען זעט אין יענעם אַ חסרון שפּיגלט זיך אָפּ אַליין. מען זעט אַמאָל אין שפּיגל אַ חי' רעה און דאָס זעט אויף יענעם אַ חסרון

And

[כתר שם טוב > הוספות > קעו](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/bsht/kst/3/176.htm)

> תורתו של הבעל שם טוב, שכאשר אדם רואה רע בזולתו, הרי זו הוכחה ש(דוגמת) אותו הרע נמצא בו בעצמו. וכמו אדם המביט בראי – "אם פניו נקיים, אינו רואה במראה שום דופי", אבל אם הוא רואה לכלוך וכתם בראי, אין זה אלא משום ש"פניו מטונפין"

*2. Is this idea expressed anywhere else in Jewish literature?*

**Yes**

To add to @mevaqesh

It is also brought in  [shulchan aruch even ezer 2.2](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.2)

> Similar a person who always invalidates others, for example he puts a stain on the lineage of families or on individuals and he says about them, that that they are mamzerim then we suspect him of being a mamzer. And if he says that they are slaves then we suspect that he is a slave. And all who invalidates others, that blemish (actually) invalidates him. And likewise he who is brazen, cruel, and hates others and he doesn't show them loving kindness we suspect him the most, lest he is gibionite (see [Mishnah Torah, Isuri Biya 19:17](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960667/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Nineteen.htm)).

*3. Are there are those that disagree openly with this idea?*

**Probably not**

---

PS [lubavicher Rebbe on subject](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/11/9/114?search=%d7%9b%d7%9c+%d7%94%d7%a4%d7%95%d7%a1%d7%9c)